# Am I implementing The Code Properly For This AWT Button?

Tags: java, events, button, applet, awt

So I'm doing this assignment where i have to use pre-made code from my teacher to handle the action of a pressed button. Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
public class TextFieldsExample extends Applet{

    public void init(){
    add(new Button("Start"));
    add(new Button("End"));
    }

    public boolean action(Event evt, Object obj){
        if(evt.target instanceof Button){
        return handleButton((Button) evt.target,(String)obj);
    }
    return true;
//a bunch of other code
}
```

I wanted to be able to move the buttons around and I didn't know how because the buttons weren't given names that i could point back to in code. So instead what I opted to do (I created buttons with names I could point to first and added them):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
public class TextFieldsExample extends Applet{

Button Start = new Button("Start");
Button End = new Button("End");

    public void init(){
    add(Start);
    add(End);
    }

    public boolean action(Event evt, Object obj){
        if(evt.target instanceof Button){
        return handleButton((Button) evt.target,(String)obj);
    }
    return true;
//a bunch of other code
}
```

And now I'm getting this error:

```
Store Website\src\Store_Website.java:166: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method handleButton(java.awt.Button,java.lang.String)
location: class Store_Website
            return handleButton((Button) evt.target,(String)obj);
                   ^
```

I have a general understanding of what this code is doing but I don't see why this isn't working. Any help would be appreciated! One thing to to be aware of is that I'm just showing the affected lines hence the error happening on line 166 in the error.

This is my first Stack Overflow post and I don't know how people that answer basic questions like these are handled so please be gentle xD

Comment: You need to show the ***entire*** error message, especially the beginning, which you're missing.

Comment: As a general comment, no. You should be using an `ActionListener`, which can then be used to call some other method(s). I know your teacher provided you with the code, but AWT was superseded over 17 years ago and your teacher shouldn't be using

Comment: I edited it with the full error, pardon the mistake.

Comment: AWT was my entire grade 12 course. I sort of figured I was learning an outdated library but who am I to tell a teacher to change an entire curriculum halfway through the course?

Comment: in the middle of the semester though?

Comment: *"..who am I to tell a teacher to change an entire curriculum halfway through the course?"* It is not for your sake to tell them, but next year's students. Please refer the teacher to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).